# I want to show grandchildren records under grandparents show page... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my code, a user has students, a student has diaries, diaries have diary_entries. I want to show the diary entries of every student under the student show page. Below are my models.

Student.rb Model

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :diaries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :grade

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :diaries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subjects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
end
```

Diary.rb Model

```
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :grade
    has_many :diary_entries

    validates :diary_year, presence: true

    def self.from_student(owner, student_obj)
        new(
            user_id: owner.id,
            student_id: student_obj.id,
            grade_id: student_obj.grade_id,
            diary_year: Date.today.year
        )
    end

end
```

Diary_entry.rb Model

```
class DiaryEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :diary
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :user

  validates :lesson_date, :assignment, :assignment_due_date, :notes_to_parents, presence: true
end
```

Diary Controller

```
class DiariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_student

  def create
    @diary = Diary.from_student(current_user, @student)
    @diary.save
    redirect_to @student, notice: "Diary was successfully created."

  end

  private

  def set_student
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end
end
```

Student controller #show

```
 def show
    @diary = @student.diaries
    @diary_entries = @diary.diary_entries
  end
```

Diary_entries controller #index and Show

```
  def index
    @diary_entries = @diary.diary_entries.all
  end

  def show
    @diary_entry = DiaryEntry.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I want each student to only have 1 diary per year, so I have added a diary_year column to each diary and then added a unique index for student_id and year on the diary table.

```
  create_table "diaries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "student_id"
    t.bigint "grade_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "diary_year"
    t.index ["grade_id"], name: "index_diaries_on_grade_id"
    t.index ["student_id", "diary_year"], name: "index_diaries_on_student_id_and_diary_year", unique: true
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_diaries_on_student_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_diaries_on_user_id"
  end
```

Below is my attempted loop in the student show page.

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">

     <% @diary_entries.each do |entry| %>
       <li><%= entry.assignment %></li>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want to be able to 1. Get each student to have only 1 diary a year, 2. To show diary_entries under each students page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show `diary_entries` of `Student`, use `joins`

```
@diary_entries = DiaryEntry.joins(diary: :student)
                           .where(students: { id: @student.id })
```

More on joins - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins

Give it a try!

Comment: Works like magic.... I am just having a hard time believing that is all there was to it, after 3 days of trying. :)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Get each student to have only 1 diary a year,

To enforce one Diary object per year you could add a before_validation in the Diary model. See [Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

The callback should call a private function that checks for existing records that could conflict.

```
def ensure_valid_year
  return unless student.diaries.where(diary_year: diary_year).any?
  # code or function call here to handle rejection of the new Diary object
end
```

> 2. To show diary_entries under each students page.

You can add another relationship in the Student model.

```
has_many :diary_entries, through: :diaries
```

You can access the related DiaryEntry objects like so:

```
student1 = Student.first
student1.diary_entries
```

Comment: @samgichuru I would also encourage you to use the has_many relationship too. It lazy loads so will not cause any slow down.
In your controller you can access it with `@diary_entries = @student.diary_entries`

Comment: Wow, that is also magical :) - wish I could accept/mark as best, two answers at the same time!